# i want to a autocomplete the data based on previous data as in sign up in viber in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, select

In Viber when we signup:

if we select nepal as our country then it will automatically complete next field as +977 ......

I want similiar as this.... Is there any plugin?

***example:***
for inserting in club table....

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>COUNTRY </b></label>
    {!! Form::text('country',null,array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'tag_id')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>DEVELOPMENT REGION</b></label>
    {!! Form::text('development_region',null,array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>ZONE</b></label>
    {!! Form::text('zone',null,array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'datepicker')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>DISTRICT</b></label>
    {!! Form::text('district',null,array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>MUNICIPALITY </b></label>
    {!! Form::text('municipality',null,array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'datepicker')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>WARD NO.</b></label>
    {!! Form::text('ward_no',null,array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>TOLE</b></label>
    {!! Form::text('tole',null,array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
</div>
```

please reply..

Comment: I do not think there is a plug-in, but you could make a table of country names and codes in your database. Code some lines when you fetch country name, then the country code will be filled in. that should be not very difficult task to code.